# iPhone 6 storage, iCloud usage in general lists 2 phones

Tags: iphone

I need to know why there are two phones showing up on my iPhone  If you go to General , storage & iCloud it lists two phones, mine and another below ? I have only one and to my knowledge I'm not linked to anyone else's. thank you

Comment: If you clicked "manage" and are looking at the list of "backups" then click on the second one so you can see when it lasted backed up.  Is it your old phone perhaps?  That would be my first guess...

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely an old phone of yours; Perhaps you upgraded to a different model recently?

Either way, you should be able to click on it & then click 'delete backup'